# how to use models in django for a query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Assume that i have a table usr with feilds name and age 
table usr

```
____________
id|name   |age|

1 |dinkan | 12|

____________
```

my query is

```
select id from usr where name="dinkan" or age="20";
```

the corresponding output should be 1

so , my question is how to implement this in django 2.1 using models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one result then you should write:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.filter(Q(name="name") | Q(age="age")).first().id
```

the corresponding output will be 1.

**update:**

If you want all ids then

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.filter(Q(name="name") | Q(age="age")).values("id")
```

Comment: and if i want all id's from the table then what would be the code for that ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Q` operator provided by django models.

> Q objects provides you complete control over the where clause of the query.

use an orm query like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Table.objects.filter(Q(name="dinkan") | Q(age="20")).values("id")
```

you can read more about it [here](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/query_relatedtool.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField()
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

your model is something like that i am assuming.

```
def user():
   user = User.objects.filter(name = 'dinkan', age = '20')
```

that user will return you a queryset and if you do not have the same name and ages in your DB then you can also use 'get'.

```
user = User.objects.get(name = 'dinkan', age = '20')
```